# Cannot rewrite parameter url with htacess in WordPress

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to do a simple URL rewrite with htaccess. But continue to receive a 404 error.

This is the original URL with the parameter as at now, where "supplier" is a page on WordPress (with the p id 374):

> example.com/supplier/?merchant=gentelle

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

> example.com/supplier/gentelle

What I have tried is this (via .htaccess):

```
# Redirect Query String For Supplier :: supplier/?merchant=gentelle
# Doesn't work. WordPress does it differently? Added function action instead in file.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/supplier/
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} merchant=(\w+)
    #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} merchant=([A-Za-z0-9]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) /supplier/%1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

There are 2 variations of the query string regex I tried. Neither worked. One is commented as you may see above.

When it didn't work, I commented the whole htaccess rule set, and tried the following WordPress solution.

```
add_action( 'init', 'sv_redirect_supplier_parameter_page' );
function sv_redirect_supplier_parameter_page() {
    add_rewrite_tag("%param%", '(\d+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^supplier/([^/]*)/?','/supplier/?merchant=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

That didn't work either.

After each of the above steps, I've refreshed the WordPress permalinks by hitting the save button in the WordPress permalinks page.

Since the WordPress permalinks means that the URL is already being rewritten, I tried the htaccess rule on the unwritten URL.

The original URL, where the parameter p is the page id of course.

> example.com/?p=374&merchant=gentelle

So, I tried this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'sv_redirect_supplier_parameter_page' );
function sv_redirect_supplier_parameter_page() {
    add_rewrite_tag("%param%", '(\d+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^supplier/([^/]*)/?','/p=374&merchant=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

Again, didn't work.

One question, how, do I make this work?